# Matlab "Find" command for a list of values? How to find the index values where the values given in a list?

Tags: matlab, list-comprehension

The `find(a==100)` works for a value but not for a list of values. In Python, I would do it with list-comprehension in the style `[find(a==cc) for cc in codomain]` where `find` is the Matlab's find.

**Example**

> **Input**
>
> ```
> >> a=[100,2,333,4,50,6,700];
> >> codomain=[100,333,700];
> ```
>
> **Intended output:** find the indices for the values in codomain, any command to do this?
>
> ```
> [1,3,7]
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the function you are looking for is

```
 ismember
```

Comment: Thank you! Why do I keep forgetting this command...sure it works: `a=[100,2,333,4,50,6];vals=[100,333,6,7]; find(ismember(a,vals))`. It is easy to overthink in different language that you are using more often.

Comment: you may also be interested in "intersect" for bidirectional matching http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html

Comment: to clarify - i meant the ia and ib in --- 

 [C, ia ,ib] = intersect(A,B)